# How to hide images on all pages except 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using python 3.5, and I am quite new. I am trying to figure out if you click on a button, you go to a 2nd page, and on that 2nd page, an image appears.

```
    myimage = PhotoImage(file='cookiesPic.gif')
    label = Label(image=myimage)
    label.image = myimage # the reference

    label.pack()
```

I have code here, but the problem is the image shows up on all pages, even the homescreen. Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Difficult to know without more code. Does `label` not have parent widget?

Comment: sorry i'm not really sure what that means, I just started trying to figure out tkinter. My program is basically a bunch of classes and defs within them. I put that code in the class that represents the first page along with all the buttons on that page, and an image was able to appear, i just cant figure out how to hide it when necessary.

Comment: Ahh it worked! Your a life saver, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
label = Label(image=myimage)
```

to

```
label = Label(self, image=myimage)
```

The first parameter `master` has a default value of `None`, which means no parent and I'm guessing means it floats off by itself and has no part in the widget hierarchy. If you give the label a parent, it will fall into line and will be hidden when its parent is hidden.